# Ruby API response - how to action

Tags: ruby

Learning Ruby & APIs. Practicing with the Uber API. Wrote a script to estimate the price of a ride.

```
require 'uber'
require 'geocoder'

def ride()

    # print "start? "
    # location_start = gets.chomp
    # print "finish? "
    # location_end = gets.chomp

    coordinates_start = Geocoder.coordinates("dublin") # gets a location for start and transforms into lat long
    coordinates_end = Geocoder.coordinates("dalkey") # gets a location for start and transforms into lat long

    client = Uber::Client.new do |config|
      config.server_token  = "{SERVER_TOKEN}"
      config.sandbox       = true
    end
    estimate = client.price_estimations(start_latitude: coordinates_start[0], start_longitude: coordinates_start[1],
                             end_latitude: coordinates_end[0], end_longitude: coordinates_end[1])
    estimate

end

puts ride
```

the output of estimate has the format `#<Uber::Price:0x00007fc663821b90>`. I run `estimate.class` and it's an array. I run `estimate[0].class` and I get `Uber::Price`. How can I extract the values that I should be getting from Uber's API response? [0]

[0] https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get#response

Comment: what do you get when you call `to_s` on `estimate` object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking to the API via a library, normally you'd follow the documentation of that library [uber-ruby](https://github.com/sishen/uber-ruby).

Unfortunately that library doesn't document what an `Uber::Price` does. It's a safe guess that Uber::Price has the same fields as in the API documentation. [Peaking at the code for Uber::Price](https://github.com/sishen/uber-ruby/blob/master/lib/uber/models/price.rb) we see this is basically correct.

```
attr_accessor :product_id, :currency_code, :display_name,
              :estimate, :low_estimate, :high_estimate,
              :surge_multiplier, :duration, :distance
```

You can access the API fields with `estimate.field`. For example, to see all estimates and durations...

```
estimates = ride()

estimates.each do |estimate|
    puts "Taking a #{estimate.display_name} will cost #{estimate.estimate} #{estimate.currency_code} and take #{estimate.duration / 60} minutes"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I am the maintainer and co-author of [`uber-ruby`](https://github.com/AnkurGel/uber-ruby) gem. @Schwern is correct, the client library gives the attributes same as that in uber api response's structure. I should probably indicate that in the documentation.

Please also note that test specs of the gem are 100% covered and it can give you the idea of how to interact with the gem, wherever it's unclear.

For price estimate, you can refer to https://github.com/AnkurGel/uber-ruby/blob/master/spec/lib/api/price_estimates_spec.rb#L61-L73

Comment: Some enterprising user could [update the README.md](https://github.com/AnkurGel/uber-ruby/blob/master/README.md) or [add detailed documentation](https://yardoc.org/).